# How to arrive at $\int_{0}^{1} f^3(x) \, dx < (\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Define $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ differentiable satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $0<f'(x)<1$.

Prove:  $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f^3(x) \, dx < \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx\right)^2$

I found the following answer,

> Define $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f^3(t) \, dt - \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)^2$
>
> We have $$F'(x)=f^3(x)-2 \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)f(x)=f(x)\left[f^2(x)-2 \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)\right]$$
> and
> $$\left[f^2(x)-2 \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)\right]'=2f(x)\left[f'(x)-1\right]$$
> from which we can arrive at the conclusion.

But I felt a little confused.

In the past I usually proved the inequality by classical inequalities and something like Taylor expansion to use the condition about derivative.

But this answer is little out of my expectation.

**Do we have other proofs or ideas to arrive at $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f^3(x) \, dx < \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx\right)^2$? And other thoughts about solving these types of issues?**

**I think when we talk about $\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx\right)^2 >\ldots \,$ it's a little difficult to deal with. I don't quite know what tools to use.**

Comment: I get the feeling that it's related to the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=(\sum_{k=1}^n k)^2$. Perhaps this could be used in a proof somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \langle 0,1]$. As the solution states, we have
$$\left[f(x)^2-2 \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)\right]'=2f(x)\left[f'(x)-1\right] < 0$$
so $f(x)^2 < 2\displaystyle\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ for all $x \in \langle 0,1]$. Also notice that $\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)' = f(x)$ so

\begin{align}
\int_0^1f(x)^3\,dx &= \int_0^1f(x)^2\, f(x)\,dx \\
&< \int_0^12 \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)\left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)'\,dx \\
&= \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt\right)^2\Bigg|_0^1 \\
&= \left(\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt\right)^2
\end{align}

---

If we assume $f \in C^1[0,1]$, we can prove the first inequality even easier:

$$f(x)^2 = \int_0^x 2f(t)\,f'(t)\,dt< 2\displaystyle\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $F(x) = \int_0^x f(x)dx$ and $I= \int_0^1 f(x)dx$. Using integration by parts formula, we get
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1 f(x)^3dx &=& (F(x)-F(1))f(x)^2 \Big|^{x=1}_{x=0} + 2\int_0^1  (F(1)-F(x))f(x)f'(x)dx\\
&<&2\int_0^1  (F(1)-F(x))f(x)dx = -(F(1)-F(x))^2\Big|^{x=1}_{x=0} = F(1)^2 =I^2.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Note: However, this calculation is only valid under the assumption that $f$ is absolutely continuous, or $f'$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: I believe this implicitly assumes that $f'$ is integrable. Still, $+1$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Oops, I missed it. Thanks for your valuable comment!